# Including image in Wenhixin bootstrap-table

Tags: javascript, image, bootstrap-table

I am working with Wenhixin bootstrap-table.js. My table should look the below table. 
[image: table]
Code for creating table is given below

```
<table class="table-bodered" data-classes="table table-hover table-condensed" data-toggle="table" data-url="http://localhost:1337/users" data-pagination="true" data-search="true" data-height="600">
                                                    <thead>
                                                        <tr>
                                                            <th data-field="profile_url">Picture</th>
                                                            <th data-field="fullname">Name</th>
                                                            <th data-field="SerialNo">Phone Number</th>
                                                            <th data-field="username">Login ID</th>
                                                            <th data-field="Image">Action</th>

                                                        </tr>
                                                    </thead>
                                                </table>
```

However, without converting image-url to image, the table looks like the below one
[image: table with image URL]

In order to get profile picture in the table , I have written the below code.

```
var data;

        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "http://localhost:1337/users",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            data: "",
            success: function (data) {
                console.log(data); //This is your result 

                console.log(data[1].profile_url);
                for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                    var node = document.createElement("LI");
                    var x = document.createElement("IMG");

                    x.setAttribute("src", data[1].profile_url);
                    x.setAttribute("width", "304");
                    x.setAttribute("width", "228");
                    x.setAttribute("alt", "The Pulpit Rock");
                    node.appendChild(x);
                    document.getElementById("myList").appendChild(node);

                }

            }
        });
```

From there, I could get the image from url which is fetched from server. This became difficult for me to place this image in the column of Picture (As it is shown in the screenshot). 
Now, I am wondering how to place this image to  which is dynamically created by Bootstrap-table.js
Quick answers will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 11):

you can use cell format

```
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <h1>Format</h1>
        <p>Use <code>formatter</code> column option to format the display of bootstrap table column.</p>
        <table id="table"
               data-toggle="table"
               data-height="460"
               data-url="../json/data1.json">
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <th data-field="profile_url" data-formatter="imageFormatter">Picture</th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
        </table>
    </div>
<script>

    function imageFormatter(value, row) {
      return '<img src="'+value+'" />';
    }
</script>
```

you can refer to the document

http://issues.wenzhixin.net.cn/bootstrap-table/#options/format.html

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It would be great help if you can show how to implement data[1].profile_url in the above code. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think, you don't need to implement data[1].profile_url, the imageFormatter is used to transform the "url" to "img", it will render the img instead of the image url

Comment: Here is an example: http://issues.wenzhixin.net.cn/bootstrap-table/#issues/579.html and an issue: https://github.com/wenzhixin/bootstrap-table/issues/579

Comment: I use a similar solution for file downloads. I love the flexibility of this cell formatter.

Comment: @Sean Thank you so much :) :D

Comment: Does the image export on excell?